# mysql_real_connect call from within daemon plugin

Tags: mysql, c

I want to write a MySQL daemon plugin that monitors queries on other MySQL servers and compares them with queries running on where the daemon is running. Basically this is in a spider engine setting, where a query initiated on the head node get run on the shards. Whenever a query is killed on the head, I want to have a daemon on the shard nodes that will kill the associated query there.

The idea was to initiate a pthread that uses `mysql_real_connect`, `mysql_real_query`... to access "show processlist" on the head node and compare them with local thread list. If I issue `mysql_real_connect` in the thread of the daemon, I get a segmentation fault. I think this is due to a threading issue in `mysql_real_connect`. I've used `#define MYSQL_SERVER 1` and follow the approach taken in `ha_federated::real_connect()`.

Is it actually possible to run `mysql_real_connect` from within a daemon plugin?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

After meditating over the handlersocker daemon plugin I realised that in order for `mysql_real_connect` and friends to work in the daemon thread, a mysql internal thread environment needs to be set up and registered with the server.

This basically involves calling the following in the daemon thread:

```
my_thread_init();
thd = new THD;

mysql_mutex_lock(&LOCK_thread_count);
thd->thread_id = thread_id++;
mysql_mutex_unlock(&LOCK_thread_count);

thd->store_globals();

... setting up various options in THD ...

mysql_mutex_lock(&LOCK_thread_count);
threads.append(thd);
++thread_count;
mysql_mutex_unlock(&LOCK_thread_count);
```